# Nhibernate mapping Lazy load no-Proxy

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Hi a have following inheritance :

```
class A {

 } class B : A {

 } 
class C { 
    public A Product{get;set} 
}
```

and fluent mapping 
where i map C like :

> References(x => x.Product).Cascade.SaveUpdate();

when i try to convert Product to B a get cast exception because nhibernate return a proxy of type A , i tried to set up 
lazy load no proxy for that property but it didn't work :
References(x => x.Product).LazyLoad(Laziness.NoProxy).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
how can i fix it ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

3 Options:

1) disable LazyLoading for this reference

2) ReferenceAny: stores the type of A in Table of C

3) Use Polymorphism instead of casting